# Chrome on mobile ignores autocapitalize="none"

Tags: android, google-chrome, capitalization

When I focus a text input field on Chrome on Android, the shift key is enabled ⇪, even though I set `autocapitalize="none"`.

The input for this field is case-sensitive, so how can I help Android users to write lower-case strings by default?

Answer (score 0):

### Tests

Tested on Android 10, `Chrome v85.0.4183.127` with `Gboard`.

```html
<input autocapitalize="off"></input>
```

Works as expected, not capitalizing a single word.

```html
<input autocapitalize="none"></input>
```

Also works as expected, not capitalizing a single word.

### Suggestion

You may want to try using `autocapitalize="off"` (seems to be more restrictive than `none` in the meaning of the word, but the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize) states they should be the same).

Given that this works as expected for me, it is possible that your software keyboard software is being troublesome. Try downloading and checking with `Gboard` and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: `off` doesn't work for me either. I test on an Huawei phone, it comes with Microsoft Swiftkey installed. Wasn't aware that could make a difference..

Comment: @jornane It's my guess that the software keyboard can probably override the browser's request to not capitalize. Try `Gboard`.